# Rails user class no responding to method, giving undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have generated a `User` model along with 2 other accompanying models called `Update` and `Round`. The `User` class responds to rounds and updates in the console but not when I call for it in the browser.

In console

```
:001 > user = User.first
:002 > user.updates
 Update Load (0.2ms) SELECT "updates".* FROM "updates" WHERE "updates"."user_id" = 1
 => [] //expected since there are no updates in the database but it responds
```

**/user/1/update error**

```
undefined method 'updates' for #<Class:0x98afa1c>
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :admin, :name, :provider :uid
  has_many :rounds
  has_many :updates

end
```

**Update.rb**

```
class Updates < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :user_id :recpcount
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Updates_controller.rb**

```
class UpdatesController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @hist = User.updates.find(params[id])
  end
end
```

Im sure I messed something simple up somewhere. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console you're calling `updates` on a User *instance*, but in the controller you're calling it on the User *class* itself.

You may instead want:

```
@hist = User.find(params[:id]).updates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@hist = User.updates.find(params[id])
```

Here's your problem.  `User` the class does not have `updates`, instances do.  You probably want:

```
@user = User.find(params[id])
@hist = @user.updates
```